# Filtering by Milestones on ComboBox

Tags: rally

I've been implementing some filters onto some Rally Apps that track Defects so far and the fields I've used to filter on have all been of 'string' type.

I was wondering if it would be possible to add a comboBox drop down filter for Milestones. I believe the answer to this question is no, because the Milestones are not tied to the 'Defect' model at all and is a Collection object as opposed to a string object. I imagine some degree of hydrating the Milestones may be involved to achieve this result, but quite honestly I'm just not sure. So I wanted to seek the veteran advice of Rally Developers on SO, so-- is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck!  The Milestones collection is actually on the Artifact type, which Defect inherits from.  There is a [MilestoneComboBox](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.combobox.MilestoneComboBox) you can use for selecting one, and then you can use a filter like this to query for matching results:

```
{
    property: 'Milestones',
    operator: 'contains',
    value: '/milestone/12345' //the value of the combobox
}
```